# How do I increase my Anaconda environment's default command prompt size?

Tags: windows, anaconda

Every time I launch a Windows command prompt with a virtual environment from Anaconda Navigator, the default buffer size very small. I would like it to be as big as possible. If I change the buffer size property, the prompt stays at the same size (not what I expect). Changing the defaults doesn't seem to have an affect either.

My question is, how do I change the buffer size of the command prompt that is launched from Anaconda Navigator?